# Why is my RAZER USB headset not recognized as an audio device?

Tags: drivers, sound, usb, 22.04

I recently got a new computer up and running with a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 and found that my RAZER USB headset is not being recognized as an audio device. Running `lsusb` shows that it is connected as a USB device, but `aplay -l` doesn';t show it at all. I've installed PulseAudio and it doesn't recognize it either, and installing the OpenRAZER driver didn't help. How can I make my system recognize this device as headphones?

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 1b1c:1bed Corsair CORSAIR K60 PRO TKL RGB Optical-Mechanical Gaming Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 3142:5060  Fifine Microphone
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0e8d:0616 MediaTek Inc. Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 048d:5702 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1532:052e Razer USA, Ltd Razer BlackShark V2 Pro
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC897 Analog [ALC897 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you certain that you checked the wires and plugged in the right device? Your 1b1c is Corsair and you would expect Razer as 1a58

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything's connected, I believe that device is the Bluetooth mouse I have connected. Razer is lower on the list. I'll give it a double check though!

Comment: The `/usr/share/misc/pci.ids` data for "1532:052e Razer USA" is also missing. The solution might to be add a rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d` to recognize the new device, but I'm not familiar with the syntax